# Rails3 localization with views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, view, routes

haven't found anything about localized views in rails3. what do i need to get views like

```
index.en.html.erb
index.de.html.erb
```

working? how to set the routes?

thanks!

Comment: Generally, only the text changes and is extracted in yml files. If more should change, what about creating separate partials for each view?

Comment: in the rails guides i read, that there's a way to use custom views for each language. how about that? what do i need else? thanks

Comment: you're definitely right, I ignored that. The guide itself doesn't really recommend it: if ever you change a view, you have to propagate modifications everywhere. Making it work seems pretty automatic: once you set your locale, the proper view is loaded. So set your locale this way: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale

Answer (score 1):

Your own settings in your `config/application.rb` file will provide the default locale (it's `en` if not set, so that `index.en.html.erb` view will already work right now).

The only thing you need to do is to provide some mechanism for your users to select/change their locale, either something manual that the user triggers eg. a link on your pages that allows them to change languages or something more automatic, eg. the user's language preferences in their profile/session or something like that.

Either way, I strongly recommend using a subdomain - it's simple to set up, stays put once you've set it up, and allows a user to send their own language link to others without having to do anything special.

[Check the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-domain-name), for more on how to do this.